# How can I reorder the visible cells in collectionView from a location search in swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am using MAPKit to search nearby locations and display them into a collectionView controller. I managed to do that and it works pretty well. Now I am trying to filter the results to show me only results in a specific distance. It worked but I can not manage to make it work properly: I did that by setting the cell hidden for cells that are not within the distance in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Now the collectionView shows gaps between cells as they are not rearranged. How can I manage to do that? I will deeply appreciate some help as I am struggling with this for quite a long time. :)

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
    var matchingItems:[MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LocationCell", for: indexPath) as! LocationCell
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.3).cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.3

        theIndex = indexPath.row

        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.itemName.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.itemAddress.text = parseAddress(selectedItem: selectedItem)

        //LOGIC: Current location - business location / transform into points / get distance in between
        let currentLocation = locationManager.location?.coordinate
        let currentUserLocation = CLLocation(latitude: (currentLocation?.latitude)!, longitude: (currentLocation?.longitude)!)
        let locationMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(currentUserLocation.coordinate)

        let coordinates = selectedItem.coordinate
        let itemsMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinates)

        let distance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(locationMapPoint, itemsMapPoint)

        let distanceInMiles = (distance / 1000) / 1.6
        cell.itemMiles.text = "\(String(format: "%.1f", distanceInMiles)) miles"

        if distanceInMiles <= setRadius {
            cell.isHidden = false

            let visibleRows = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.count
            print("Visible: \(visibleRows)")


        } else if distanceInMiles > setRadius {
            cell.isHidden = true

            if cell.isHidden {
                let matches = 0
                if matches == indexPath.row {
                    //matchingItems.remove(at: matches)
                    print("Hidden at: \(matches)")
                    //collectionView.reloadData()
                }

            }

        }

        if matchingItems.isEmpty {
            print("all is empty....")
        } else {

        }
        return cell
    }
```

And this is the error I am getting:
(In this example cell 0 and 5 is displayed the rest are hidden being more than the radius)
[image: In this example cell 0 and 5 is displayed the rest are hidden being more than the radius]

Comment: Just reorder/remove items from `matchingItems`.

Comment: How do I reorder them? I tried with sort but matchingItems is of kind MKMapItem were I can only use map items. Can you show me an example?